# Is there a problem when the lower and upper limits of a confidence interval are the same?

Tags: cross-validation

I have done the bootstrap technique and I want to make inference. I have calculated the 95% confidence intervals, however, for one of the variables in my regression model its lower and upper limits are equal, is this a problem?

Comment: Unless we have amazing precision in our estimates and/or looking at a deterministic effect (as well as probably some unintentional rounding of values) this is highly unlikely. I would urge you to look at this very carefully. This seems wrong.

Comment: What kind of bootstrap did you calculate? Was it empirical or parametric or something else? Specifically, how did you get from your data to the CI (of what parameter)?